# How do I get a button's bg color?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I want to know how to get the value of the button's background color or change the value of the button's background color.

This is for a school project and I'm trying to make a working checkerboard.

#### Code

```
import tkinter as tk

class Checkers(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(
            self, width=32, height=35, 
            background='black', command=self.movebutton()
        ).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

    def movebutton(self):
        if self.button['bg'] == 'black':
            self.button = tk.Button(
                self, width=4, height=2, background='red4'
            ).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Checkers")
root.geometry("600x400")
app = Checkers(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I wanted for a red square to replace the black one but I'm getting an error "AttributeError: 'Checkers' object has no attribute 'button'"

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by line 12 and 13 where you wrote `command=self.movebutton()`. It should just be `command=self.movebutton`. For the `command` option, you are to reference the function you want to execute instead of executing it. Putting `()` symbol after the function name means you are executing(not referencing) the function. It is an error because while creating the attribute `self.button` (i.e. tkinter has yet to create it), you are also executing a function that uses `self.button`.